# jboss server cannot load WAR with Log4J

Tags: maven, log4j, jboss-eap-6

I'm trying to use Log4J within a Maven project that is being run by a local jboss EAP 6.1 server.  Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>pro</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.company.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>com.company.test.project</name>

  <dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.5</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

I have a log4j.xml file placed under webapp\WEB-INF-classes.  It seems like jboss is having an issue loading the project because the log4j.xml contains an SMTP appender:

```
<appender name="EMAIL" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
<param name="From"      value="support@company.com"/>
<param name="SMTPHost"  value="smtp1.server.com"/>
<param name="Subject"   value="Fatal Error"/>
<param name="To"        value="user@company.com"/>
<param name="Threshold" value="FATAL" />
</appender>
```

When I try to run the project locally, I get this error:

```
15:07:17,389 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread
1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service
jboss.deployment.unit."com.company.test.project.war".POST_MODULE:
org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
jboss.deployment.unit."com.company.test.project.war".POST_MODULE:
JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment
"com.company.test.project.war"    at
org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127)
[jboss-as-server-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]     at
org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
[jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]   at
org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
[jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]   at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
[rt.jar:1.7.0_55]     at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
[rt.jar:1.7.0_55]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[rt.jar:1.7.0_55] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
javax/mail/internet/AddressException  at
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
[rt.jar:1.7.0_55]     at
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493)
[rt.jar:1.7.0_55]     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2803)
[rt.jar:1.7.0_55]     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:345)
[rt.jar:1.7.0_55]     at
    org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:247)
      at
    org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:176)
      at
    org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191)
      at
    org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:523)
      at
    org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:492)
      at
    org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:1001)
      at
    org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:867)
      at
    org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:794)
      at
org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingDeploymentUnitProcessor.configure(LoggingDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:295)
[jboss-as-logging-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]    at
org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingDeploymentUnitProcessor.processDeploymentLogging(LoggingDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:176)
[jboss-as-logging-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]    at
org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingDeploymentUnitProcessor.deploy(LoggingDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:81)
[jboss-as-logging-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]    at
org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120)
[jboss-as-server-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]     ...
5 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
javax.mail.internet.AddressException from [Module
"org.jboss.log4j.logmanager:main" from local module loader @b7e2544
(finder: local module finder @6c09941 (roots:
C:\Users\sobczakm\EAP-6.1\jboss-eap-6.1\modules,C:\Users\sobczakm\EAP-6.1\jboss-eap-6.1\modules\system\layers\soa,C:\Users\sobczakm\EAP-6.1\jboss-eap-6.1\modules\system\layers\sramp,C:\Users\sobczakm\EAP-6.1\jboss-eap-6.1\modules\system\layers\base))]
  at
org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:196)
[jboss-modules.jar:1.2.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:444)
[jboss-modules.jar:1.2.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:432)
[jboss-modules.jar:1.2.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:374)
[jboss-modules.jar:1.2.2.Final-redhat-1]  at
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:119)
[jboss-modules.jar:1.2.2.Final-redhat-1]  ... 21 more

15:07:17,389 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads -
1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "com.company.test.project.war" was
rolled back with the following failure message:  {"JBAS014671: Failed
services" =>
{"jboss.deployment.unit.\"com.company.test.project.war\".POST_MODULE"
="org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"com.company.test.project.war\".POST_MODULE:
JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment
\"com.company.test.project.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/internet/AddressException
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.internet.AddressException from [Module
\"org.jboss.log4j.logmanager:main\" from local module loader @b7e2544
(finder: local module finder @6c09941 (roots:
C:\\Users\\sobczakm\\EAP-6.1\\jboss-eap-6.1\\modules,C:\\Users\\sobczakm\\EAP-6.1\\jboss-eap-6.1\\modules\\system\\layers\\soa,C:\\Users\\sobczakm\\EAP-6.1\\jboss-eap-6.1\\modules\\system\\layers\\sramp,C:\\Users\\sobczakm\\EAP-6.1\\jboss-eap-6.1\\modules\\system\\layers\\base))]"}}
```

EDIT: here is the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file I created:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: I don't know your whole dev-environment. But it seems, you are importing some log4j-module ("org.jboss.log4j.logmanager:main") already. This means, the log4j-module inside your war is not used to parse xml-config. Later, the module-log4j can't find the class AddressException because it can't access your war libs.

Comment: Please add jboss-deployment-structure.xml or your Meta-inf/Manifest.MF Dependencies, depending on where you define your imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug that was fixed in EAP 6.3 which adds the correct dependencies to the log4j module used in EAP. If you add the following dependencies `$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/log4j/logmanager/main/module.xml` it should fix it.

```xml
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.mail.api" optional="true"/>
    <module name="javax.jms.api" optional="true"/>
    <module name="org.dom4j" optional="true"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.logmanager"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.modules"/>
</dependencies>
```

The other option is to use a [`jboss-deployment-structure.xml`](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIuselog4j.propertiesorlog4j.xmlinsteadofusingtheloggingsubsystemconfiguration%3F) to exclude log4j and use the version you're providing.

Comment: I created the jboss-deployment-structure.xml and placed under webapp/WEB-INF.  I'm getting the following error with the file:  
cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'deployment' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only. jboss-deployment-structure.xml /com.company.test.project/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF line 2 XML Problem.  I'll paste the contents of the file in the question above.

Comment: Not sure why it didn't work. I just tested and it works fine for me. Is this an error in your IDE?

Comment: Yes, in the IDE.  I'm using JBoss Developer Studio 7.1.1

Comment: I think if you remove the `xmlns` part it might work. It just can't find the schema.

Comment: Yep, that was it.  I removed the namespace attribute and the file now has no errors in the IDE.  Thanks!